# how to assign array element value to ng-click in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

In my program I have an `Array` which consists of header name and function name.
I am using `ng-repeat` in a `div` which consists of a `span` tag. I want to add different functionality for each iterated span so I stored function name in array.
   my html code is:

```
   <div ng-repeat="header in header" ng-init="head=header">
       <h4 class="headers">{{ header.name}}</h4>
       <div class="arrow-up" ng-show={{ header.arrowup}} ng-click={{header.close}}> </div>
   </div>
```

my angular code is:

```
   $scope.header=[{"name":"Subsection Header #1","arrowup":"arrowup","close":"close()"}];
    $scope.close = function() {
        console.log(hello);

    };
```

I want to assign  close() to the ng-click and arrowup to ng-show. How can I assign them to `ng-click` and `ng-show`

Comment: what are you trying to do here? why do you want the method names to come out of that JSON?

Comment: Please explain little more about this

Comment: use those methods i have set to visibility for different div's

Comment: i want to assign the close:close() element to the ng-click using ng-repeat

Comment: where is the `close` function declared?

Comment: is the `close` function declared inside a the current controller? Can you please update your question with the declaration of the `close` function?

Comment: @VJayanthReddy check my answer.

Comment: please see my answer, according to the angularjs documentation this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
 <div class="arrow-up" ng-show={{ header.arrowup}} ng-click={{header.close}}>
```

To:

```
   <div class="arrow-up" ng-show="header.arrowup" ng-click="this[header.close]()">
         <button>
         CLOSE ME 
         </button>
       </div>
```

DEMO= http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1788/

Answer (score 0):

ng-click is the problem as i see,

```
<div class="arrow-up" ng-show="header.arrowup" ng-click="header.close"></div>
```

we need not give {{}} to ng-click and ng-show.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass a real functions to array:

```
function arrowUp(){
 // ng-show needs to receive true or false
  return true;
}

function close(){
 // do something here
}
  $scope.headers=[{"name":"Subsection Header #1","arrowup":arrowUp,"close":close}];
```

The bind them in a view:

```
 <div ng-repeat="header in headers">
       <h4 class="header">{{ header.name}}</h4>
       <div class="arrow-up" ng-show="header.arrowup()" ng-click="header.close()"> </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$eval` method, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

> **$scope.$eval** Executes the expression on the current scope and returns the result. Any exceptions in the expression are propagated (uncaught). This is useful when evaluating Angular expressions

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="header in headers">
    <h4>{{ header.name}}</h4>
    <button type="button" ng-click="onExecuteFunctionFromString(header.close)">Click Here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.headers = [{
    "name": "Subsection Header #1",
    "arrowup": "arrowup",
    "close": "close()"
  }];
  $scope.close = function() {
    console.log('hello');
  };
  $scope.onExecuteFunctionFromString = function(stringFunction) {
    $scope.$eval(stringFunction)
  };
}]);
```

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/aszLzphj/3/)